# Clear cell values in SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which is processing the following sorted data:

```
GroupName  Value1 Value2  Value3
A          100    200     5
A          100    200     10
A          100    200     15
B          300    400     1
B          300    400     2
B          300    400     3
```

I want to transform this such that for each distinct GroupName, I keep Value1 for the first record only and Value2 for the last record only, and clear out all other Value1 and Value2 fields as follows:

```
GroupName  Value1 Value2  Value3
A          100    0       5
A          0      0       10
A          0      200     15
B          300    0       1
B          0      0       2
B          0      400     3
```

How can this be achieved (maybe through a script)?

Comment: I dont think SSIS is the right tool to do this kind of manipulation. Maybe you want to write a stored proc?

Comment: I agree it might not be the best tool.  But unfortunately this is just a small task that needs to be done at the end of a large SSIS package, so it would need to be done through SSIS as well.  The data above comes following several processes on a number of data sources, and does not all come from a database either.

Comment: I really cannot think of a way to do this. Even if you were to use a recordset destination, you would still need to perform SQL operation on this. SSIS simply would be too prohibitive, IMHO, to perform this.

Comment: A script, acting as an asynchronous, partially blocking component is the route I'd look at. Still working on the implementation though